# How can i express non central chi square random variable in terms of gamma function?

Tags: distributions, gamma-distribution, non-central

I know the relation between central chi square and gamma random variables.But i am not able to get relation between gamma and non central chi-square distribution.

Comment: Exactly what kind of "relation" are you seeking?  Non-central chi-squares are not gammas, but there are various ways they could be expressed as mixtures of gammas and possibly there are good approximations using small finite mixtures of gammas.

Comment: Yes , I am seeking a easy and simple approximation of non central chi square to gamma distribution.

Comment: A Master's thesis by Bill Weston (1978) at https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/bitstream/handle/2346/12849/31295004138185.pdf?sequence=1 gives an overview of such approximations.

Comment: Thanks @whuber !!